# Creating table of contents within google documents from numbered list to have numbering visible

Tags: google-docs, tableofcontents

How to create table of contents within google documents from numbered list to have numbering visible ?

I have created numbered list with levels (Heading 1, 2, 3) but within the table of contents created just after there are only topics visible but not numbers for relevant levels.
For Example:

```
1. Topic one, 
1.1 Subtopic ... etc,
```

but in table of contents there are only visible

```
Topic one, 
Subtopic ... etc,
```

but without 1, 1.1 ... etc,

Please advice. 
Thanks

Comment: Added google-docs tag and corrected typo in title

Comment: Liza, Thanks for advice Why is it not organized by simply formatting within tool itself ?